# Is there a way to prove that one sieve will have a bigger remaining set than another?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Like if we have a sieve that sieves to get all mersenne primes and a sieve that sieves to find all twin primes for instance?

Comment: Depending on whether or not there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, and whether or not there are infinitely many Twin primes. **Neither** one of these facts have been proven or refuted as of yet, and **both** of them need to be, in order to answer your question. So it's impossible to provide answer to this question (i.e., maybe there is a way, but no one has yet to find it).

Comment: @barakmanos But when we see that the sieve to sieve for mersenne primes is a sieve of all prime multiples and prime (without 2) multiples + 1

Comment: @barakmanos and the sieve of twin primes is the sieve of prime multiples and prime (without 2) multiples + 2, does that not make them comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is very difficult to establish lower bounds for thin sequences via sieve theory. So while Brun's theorem (an upper bound for twin primes) was proved almost 100 years ago, we still can't prove any infinite lower bound for twin primes. Indeed, modern upper bounds for the twin primes are only off by a constant factor from what we believe to be true.

Sieving for Mersenne primes is much harder than sieving for twin primes because the structure of the divisors is more complex. But even here the same general rule holds: upper bounds are easier than lower bounds.

Comment: But let's say a prime number sieve where multiples of 3 are not sieved versus a prime number sieve where multiples of 2 aren't sieved, is that something that can be done?

Comment: For small modifications like that you'd be better off doing it directly rather than redoing the sieve. The variants you mention yield numbers of the form 3^e * p and 2^e * p where e >= 0 and p is prime, and it's not hard to see that these have density 1.5 n/log n and 2n/log n.